# Python regex optional capture group with positive lookahead

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

trying to find certain folder patterns. i can have a simple if statement but now I am wondering, Can this be done in one regex pattern?

folders:

```
name
name_a01
name_a02
..
name_a20
```

`name_dontuse_a10`   < dont want this pattern

```
pattern = re.match(".*name(_a[0-9])?", dir)
```

the above matches correctly but it matches both `name` and `name_dontuse_a10`

```
pattern.group(1)
```

return `None` for both those folder so that doesn't help me much.

I cant predict what the unwanted folders will be named but I want both the base name folder and any `name_a## folder`. I think I need a postie lookahead but unsure how to use that with an optional capture group.

Comment: Hey, you may want to take a look at my answer. The other answer has a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this one:

```
pattern = re.match(".*name(_a[0-9]*)?$", dir)
```

I just added `$` to match the end of the string after the first underscore. I also added `[0-9]*` to match zero or more digits.

Live Example:

https://regex101.com/r/MSldc6/2/

Comment: ah so simple, 0 or more of the numbers, 0 or 1 of the group match, at the end of the string

Comment: Also note that the `(_a[0-9]*)?` bit is saying optionally match the pattern `_a[0-9]*` once. Which allows it to match the case of `name` but also `name_a99` while correctly failing on `name_a99_99`

Comment: I think this solution can be improved because `.*` can match anything before name. Consider that it will match `'dir1/dir2/junk_name'`.

Comment: In regards to OP's question, this is wholly sufficient, the `.*` is a quick and dirty way to match the full path - since OP didn't provide a full sample path, it's possible we need to match `C://Users/.../.../name_a90` so unless the problem is provided with more specificity, this should be fine.

Comment: Do you think OP wants to match `junk_name`? Probably not. I see it as a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The  best solution is to first extract the filename out of the path, so you don't have to deal with it in your regex. `normpath` removes any trailing `/` and `basename` extracts the filename. So for `dir1/dir2/name/` you get `name`.

```
import os, re

dir = ...
name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(dir))

pattern = re.match("name(_a\d+)?", name)
```

Note that what was happening in your original solution was that `.*` was matching the entire string, leading to an unexpected behavior.

Comment: I am matching folders and not files